# Marshal/Unmarshal google.protobuf.Any proto message

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

I'm currently using gRPC for my API communication. Now I need the value of my request can accept any data type, be it a `struct object` or just a primitive data type like single `integer`, `string`, or `boolean`. I tried using `google.protobuf.Any` as below but it doesn't work when I want to marshal and unmarshal it.

```
message MyRequest {
    google.protobuf.Any item = 1; // could be 9, "a string", true, false, {"key": value}, etc.
}
```

proto-compiled result:

```
type MyRequest struct {
    Item *anypb.Any `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=item,proto3" json:"item,omitempty"`
}
```

I will marshal the incoming request through gRPC and save it as a JSON string in the database:

```
bytes, err = json.Marshal(m.request.Item)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
itemStr := string(bytes)
```

But when I want to unmarshal the string back into `*anypb.Any` by:

```
func getItem(itemStr string) (structpb.Value, error) {
    var item structpb.Value
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(itemStr), &item)
    
    if err != nil {
        return item, err
    }

    // also I've no idea on how to convert `structpb.Value` to `anypb.Any`
    return item, nil
}
```

It returns an error which seems to be because the struct `*anypb.Any` doesn't contain any of the fields in my encoded `item` string. Is there a correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: try `google.protobuf.Value` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73396864/16182150)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [anypb](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb)

In the documentation it shows an example of how to unmarshal it

```
m := new(foopb.MyMessage)
if err := any.UnmarshalTo(m); err != nil {
    ... // handle error
}
... // make use of m
```

Comment: But I need to unmarshal a string data, not `any`.

Comment: [`any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) lets you embed messages. You can't unmarshal `any` as a string. You could unmarshal a message that contains a field of type string.